# VB.NET convert UCS-2 bytes to ASCII

Tags: vb.net, tcp, character-encoding, byte, ascii

Ok so i am working on this program which sends a packet to a minecraft server and in return it gives me information about the server;(message of the day, players online, max players)

The problem is the response is in UCS-2

So when i send the packet to the server and get the response in bytes. How do i convert it to ascii so i can work with it?

Here is my code so far

```
Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
client .Connect("178.33.213.54", 25565)

Dim stream As NetworkStream = client .GetStream



'Send Bytes
Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = {&HFE}
stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

'Receive Bytes
Dim bytes(client .ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(leclient.ReceiveBufferSize))

'Convert it to ASCII
....


'Output it to Console
....
```

Here is the same code in PHP, python, and ruby.

php    ->  https://gist.github.com/1235274

python ->  https://gist.github.com/1209061

ruby   ->  http://pastebin.com/q5zFPcXV

The documentation is here:
http://www.wiki.vg/Protocol#Server_List_Ping_.280xFE.29

Thanks in advance! 
Vidhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and working.

```
Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()

client.Connect("178.33.213.54", 25565)

Dim stream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = client.GetStream

'Send Bytes
Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = {&HFE}
stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

''Receive Bytes
Dim bytes(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(client.ReceiveBufferSize))

Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For i As Integer = 3 To bytes.GetUpperBound(0) Step 2
  Dim byt2(1) As Byte
  byt2(0) = bytes(i + 1)
  byt2(1) = bytes(i)

  Dim ii As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt16(byt2, 0)
  'sb.Append(Hex(ii)) 'debug
  sb.Append(ChrW(ii))
Next i
MsgBox(sb.ToString)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: P.S. This converts to Unicode, not ASCII, because Unicode is the native format of .NET strings

Comment: hi, thanks for ur code!
can you tell me why you are stepping 2?

Comment: In your question you stated that the input stream was in UCS-2. According to Wikipedia: "Both UTF-16 and UCS-2 encode code points in this range as single 16-bit code units that are numerically equal to the corresponding code points."

I'm stepping 2 because 16 bits = 2 Bytes

Comment: OK I've updated my answer. I've tested it and it seems to work.